# thrift - address already in use

Tags: c++, linux, thrift

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Here is an example code which works:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TestHandler> handler(new TestHandler());
boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new TestProcessor(handler));
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(9090));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

thriftServerThread = std::thread(&TSimpleServer::serve, TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory));
```

When I run program `netstat -a | grep 9090` returns:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9090               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I want to use thrift server only within a localhost so I have changed:

```
 boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(9090));
```

to

```
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket("127.0.0.1:9090"));
```

When I have run a program first time I have got following info from netstat:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30808    127.0.0.1:9090
```

When I try to run program again even after system reboot I get an exception:

> > Thrift: Tue Mar  3 13:31:40 2015 TServerSocket::listen() PATH 127.0.0.1:9090
> >     terminate called after throwing an instance of 'apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
> >       what():  Could not bind: Address already in use

Netstat doesn't find that address. What is going on ? I have debugged thrift and a function

```
extern int bind (int __fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t __len)
     __THROW;
```

declared in **/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h** returns value other than zero and next an exception is thrown. How to fix that ? When I change a port my program works but only once, then again even after system reboot I get that exception.

Comment: That `netstat` output tells you that you have a `AF_LOCAL` (a.k.a. `AF_UNIX`) socket, not that it's listening to TCP (4 or 6). That means there's a file *in the file system* and it needs to be removed before you start listening on that `AF_LOCAL` "address" again.

Comment: Reading the [`TServerSocket.h`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h) header file and the `TServerSocket` constructors, it seems what you want is not possible. The constructor taking a string even have the *name*  `path`which indicates it's a `AF_LOCAL` file-path.

Comment: Where are located files connected with AF_LOCAL socket ?

Comment: I mean files which are created in the file system and which block start listening on that AF_LOCAL "address" again

Comment: Ah... Since you have a relative path, it will be in the current working directory of the process.

Comment: "*I want to use thrift server only within a localhost ...*"  -  maybe there's a slight misunderstanding here. Wherever the server runs, this is `localhost` for the server. You hardly can't open a (server) port remotely. **Clients** may connect to a remote server or a server on `localhost`. But you can't restrict what clients do by telling the server to open a port on `localhost` - that's what he does anyway. You need to block access from the outside (firewall, iptables, ...)  to prevent remote clients from accessing your server if that is your goal.

Comment: Yes, I want to block access from the outside, but what is use case for TServerSocket which takes path as constructor argument. Who create those files and why ?